# Is there a keyboard shortcut for "Build Page" in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio

"Build Page" is one of the items you can add to your toolbar to compile just the ASPX page or ASCX control you are working on.  Is there a keyboard shortcut for it?

Answer (score 1):

I always use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, which rebuilds the entire solution.

You could also configure your own keyboard shortcut by clicking Tools / Options / Keyboard and scrolling down to the Build options. (There's ones for Build.BuildPage or Build.BuildSelection...)

Comment: Rebuilding the entire solution takes way too long.  I created a custom keyboard shortcut.  It's in Tools -> Customize -> Keyboard, not Tools -> Options -> Keyboard.